# Quill - hasFocus always false but works fine

Tags: javascript, quill

Every call to quill.hasFocus returns false. I even did a setinterval for every 50ms and it never ever showed true in the console. Even while using normally. The border is lit up, I'm typing, everything seems completely normal.

If it returns false I cannot use getSelection etc.
Calling focus() has no effect, its false on the next line.
Doing getSelection(true) has no effect.

I am running quill in Electron.

EDIT:
Minimal example time:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"></script>
    <link href="node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <textarea id='quilleditor' style="width: 100%; min-height: 500px;"></textarea>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
    {
        var quill = new Quill('#quilleditor', {
            theme: 'snow'
        });

        //does not work
        quill.setText("kdjasiosaghdfiasdgfiasgdifgasdfhioasudf");

        setInterval(function(){
            //always false
            console.log("focus: " + quill.hasFocus());
        },60);

        //does not fire
        quill.on('text-change', function(delta, oldDelta, source) {
            console.log("text-change focus: " + quill.hasFocus());
        });

        //does not fire
        quill.on('selection-change', function(delta, oldDelta, source) {
            console.log("selection-change focus: " + quill.hasFocus());
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also the event text-change never ever gets fired. selection-change does seem to work. Still no focus though.

Comment: Now running the minimal example in the browser. Same result.

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, same result.

Answer (score 0):

The playground / codepen.io example worked perfectly.
So I inspected it carefully.

Here is the issue.

I used:

```
<textarea id='quilleditor' style="width: 100%; min-height: 500px;"></textarea>
```

a textarea. Which makes it not work. I thought I read that it **has** to be a textarea. My mistake i guess.